# i wanna access an object of class 1 from class 2 the **object** is from another class lets say class 3

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oop

below is the object declared as "client" , of another class that i imported called mqttAndroidClient

```
 public class connection{

 public void onCtreate(){
 String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
 MqttAndroidClient client =
           new MqttAndroidClient(getApplicationContext(), "tcp://" + TEXT + ":" + TEXT2,
            clientId);
      }
 }
```

```
the object "client" of connection class, i wanna access it from a main class
```

```
 public class main extends AppComptActivity{
 //
 //Attributes
 //
  public void onCreate(){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //onclick of button

     button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String topic = TOPIC;
            String payload = PAYLOAD;
            byte[] encodedPayload = new byte[0];
            try {
                encodedPayload = payload.getBytes("UTF-8");
                MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(encodedPayload);
                message.setRetained(true);
                client.publish(topic, message);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
     });
  }
```

in the above code it cannot identify the client as the object from connection class

`client.publish(topic, message);`

```
i have tried to call it in main using
```

`connection myobject = new connection(); myobject.onCreate();`

```
but its throwing a declaration error i am very new to java and oops and 
if the info is not efficient i will post the full code
```

Comment: You need to provide a complete, minimal example, and show exactly what error you are getting

Comment: thank you btw , it's along code but ill post it with the exact error an facing :)

Comment: Try to reduce your code to a minimal example which still shows the problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make the client object in Connection class as global variable and call the constructor which initialize the object.

```
public class Connection {

MqttAndroidClient client;
Context context;

public Connection(Context context) {
    
    this.context = context;
    initClient(context);
}

public void initClient(Context context){
    client =
            new MqttAndroidClient(getApplicationContext(), "tcp://" + TEXT1 + ":" + TEXT2,
                    clientId);
}

public MqttAndroidClient getClient(){
    return client;
}
}
```

Now inside `MainClass` first of all get the object of `Connection class` and then get the client object from connection class by calling the method which returns the client object.

> **Inside Main Class**

```
    Connection connection= new Connection(this);
    MqttAndroidClient client= connection.getClient();
```

Answer (score 0):

let me guess the problem - you want to access `client` from within the `onClick` method so that you can call `client.publish(topic, message);`, but now you are getting a compilation error. am i right ?

cause : `MqttAndroidClient client` in `onCtreate` method of `connection` is a local variable, which is created and destroyed, after the call to `onCtreate`. hence it is not accesible.

solution : make `MqttAndroidClient client` an attribute of `connection` class.

update the connection class as follows :

```
public class connection{

     private MqttAndroidClient client;

     public MqttAndroidClient getClient(){
          return this.client;
        }
         public void onCreate(){
         String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
         this.client =
                   new MqttAndroidClient(getApplicationContext(), "tcp://" + TEXT + ":" + TEXT2,
                    clientId);
              }
```

and now in the below method you can add

```
connection myobject = new connection(); 
myobject.onCreate();
myobject.getClient().publish(topic, message);
```

Comment: i tired this but  in mainActivity myobject.onCreate(); it is asking to create method "onCreate" in connection class

Comment: public void "onCtreate()" - change this spelling to "onCreate". should work..

Comment: sorry that was a typo, it is typed correctly as "onCreate();" in the code though

Comment: I am guessing you are not using the same connection class in the  _public class main extends AppComptActivity_ class, can you check the _imports_ at the top